# Get folder names of directory and insert them into string

Tags: powershell

I want to get all folder names within `C:\Users` (to get the usernames) and exclude the "Public" and "Default" user.

Then I want to insert them into a path `C:\Users\$userlist\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*.ost` so I can rename the `ost` files like this:

```
dir $ostPath | Rename-Item -NewName { [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, "bak") }
```

but every time it should take another path in the `$ostPath` variable with another username from `$userlist`.

Comment: Sounds like a great plan. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I dont now how to make a "for-loop" that goes through every path. Say I have all usernames in $userlist I have to go like for($userlist){Write-Output C:\Users\$PartOfuserlist\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook*.ost}

Comment: Take a look at `Get-ChildItem`, the `Directory` and `Exclude` parameters might help you with your problem.

Comment: Loops are basic control structures. Please go find a PowerShell tutorial. SO is not a replacement for familiarizing yourself with the language you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\Users |
? { !($_.Name -eq "Public" -or $_.Name -eq "Default.migrated")} | 
ForEach-Object {
    $FolderName=$_.Name 

    $ostPath ="C:\Users\"+$FolderName+"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*.ost"
    dir $ostPath
}
```